# mod_rewrite and mod_proxy together in Apache configuration

Tags: angular, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am using Apache server for hosting my Angular application. So I enabled the single page application support with he following configuration

```
<Location / >
   RewriteEngine on#
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</Location>
```

Also I have a backend. I am using mod_proxy to proxy it with Apache.

```
ProxyPass "/api" "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api"
ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api"
```

But when I use both these configurations, I am unable to call any APIs.
All calls return index.html.

May I know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Try adding one more condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Dusan Bajic for the comment.
Now, I have the following config, and it works.

```
ProxyPass "/api" "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api"
ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api"

<Location / >
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</Location>
```